# Getting the exception : An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied in AWS EB

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am new to Flask and Python. I am trying to upload a file in my AWS S3 bucket. While this works fine in my local, I get the following exception when I try to do the same after deploying on Elastic Beanstalk.

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

app.py

```
@app.route('/snap/ingredient', methods=['POST'])
def findIngredient():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    response = s3.Bucket('<bucket-name>').put_object(Key="image.jpeg", Body=request.files['myFile'], ACL='public-read')
    print(response.key)
    return response
```

I am not sure if I am missing something. My Bucket access is public.

Comment: You need to use an IAM Instance Profile that has access to the bucket. The default one used by Elastic Beanstalk doesn't. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html

Comment: In the IAM Policies there are a large number of policies. what do I do with them. Is there any way to attach the Policy to the EB/EC2 Instance?

Comment: All the information you need is in the document I linked. Specifically "Adding permissions to the default instance profile" might be a good start.

Comment: Thanks got it.. "AmazonS3FullAccess" this policy had to be attached. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider creating a policy only with required permissions instead of S3FullAccess.